# "Select > New 3D Extrusion" is greyed out in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Why is this greyed out? I heard that Adobe are enforcing hardware limitations.

What I'm running:

[image: Photoshop performance preferences]
[image: System statistics]

Comment: 2GHz processors have fallen out of date around now IMO, 2.5+ GHz is barely standard now, hardware upcycles every 6 - 12 months. If you decide to get a new laptop/PC go for 3GHz+, your RAM is plenty, but processor is poop, graphics card pretty old to.

Comment: Hey Starkers, this question has more to do with tech support than it does Graphic Design, so I've gotta close it. However, you answered your own question: CS6 has enforced hardware limitations. You don't have enough video memory! Check out this staff response on the Adobe forums: [Photoshop CS6 Ext spontaneously disables 3D feature...](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4937944#4937944)

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for explaining why this had to be closed...do you reckon this could be migrated to SuperUser just in case someone does have an answer?

Comment: @Starkers I'll ask the mods, hang tight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have enough video memory.  You have 256MB, but I believe that you'll need at least 512MB if not 1GB minimum.

*3D features are disabled with less than 512MB of VRAM.
http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/tech-specs.html

Comment: Darn...I'm using cinema 4D for all my 3D needs and the Macbook copes fine. Do you reckon there's anyway to trick the system into thinking a different graphics card is installed?

Answer (score 2):

Change the color mode to RGB from CMYK.

Just posting after spending 14 million years scratching a new hole in my desk. Simple fix!